# If I have 4 determinants for 4 parts of one matrix, how can I compute the determinant for the matrix as a whole?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> M=[AB 0C] (A and B build the first row, 0 and C build the second row.)

The determinant of Matrix A is 2. The determinant of Matrix B is 3. The determinant of Matrix C is 5.
What's the determinant of the Matrix M
[Here is the exercise that I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYheM.png)

Can I just use the 4 determinants to build a 2*2 matrix and then calculate "|23 05|(2 and 3 sit in the first row, 0 and 5 sit in the second row)"?

Comment: Sorry I really don't know how to type those symbols.

Comment: Here's what should help you with typesetting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [determinant of a block matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

What you describe (constructing a matrix of determinants) would yield the correct result, but would not be a valid procedure.
Namely, it's true that
$$
\mathrm{det}\bigg(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\ 0 & C
\end{array} \bigg) = \mathrm{det}(A) \cdot \mathrm{det}(C).
$$
In general, the formulas for determinants are ugly, but I would recommend reading the Wikipedia article linked above to learn more about them.